# Can't connect Lambda function to Aurora RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using the serverless framework to try and have my lambda function throw some records into an 'always on' Aurora RDS instance. So far I've been met with connect timeouts when using the mysql npm package and trying to connect to the RDS instance.

Here is what I've checked\tried:

- put the lambda function in the VPC in serverless.yml
- included the 3 subnets associated with that VPC in the yml
- specified the security group in the servless.yml
- checked that there is an aurora routing rule in that service group that allowed access to the service group itself
- added ec2 elastic interface iam role statements

serverless.yml:

```
service: myrds

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-2'}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action: 
        - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
        - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
        - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      Resource: "*"
  - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
        - "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
        - "sqs:ListQueues"
      Resource:
        Fn::GetAtt: 
          - RDSQueue
          - Arn 
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
        - "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
        - "sqs:ListQueues"
      Resource:
        Fn::GetAtt: 
          - DeadLetterQueue
          - Arn 
 functions:
   consumer:
    handler: handler.consumer
    timeout: 20
    vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-123456
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-11111
      - subnet-22222
      - subnet-33333
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - RDSQueue
              - Arn
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  resources:
    Resources:
      RDSQueue:
        Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
        Properties:
          QueueName: "RDSQueue-${opt:stage, 'dev'}"
          RedrivePolicy:
            deadLetterTargetArn:
              "Fn::GetAtt":
                - DeadLetterQueue
                - Arn
            maxReceiveCount: 3
      DeadLetterQueue:
        Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
        Properties:
          QueueName: "DeadLetterQueue-${opt:stage, 'dev'}"
```

What am I missing here? It's connect timing out when it is triggered from the SQS queue.

Comment: Have you given lambda permission to access Aurora?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I didn't see any specific iamrolestatements for aurora, assuming that's what you mean. I was looking in the SDK and under RDS I didn't see anything that was applicable for simple connect and query. Is that what you mean or are you talking about something else?

Comment: where is the database connection config in your yml?

Comment: Do the subnets have a routing table entry that point to an Internet Gateway?

Comment: @JunedAhsan it's defined in a .js file, not in the yml

Comment: @JoeyKilpatrick no, no routing to an internet gateway as this will only be used internally, no outbound access is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical configuration when connecting from an AWS Lambda function to an Amazon RDS database is:

- Lambda function connected to the private subnets in the VPC
- A Security Group on the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) with all Outbound access permitted
- A Security Group on the RDS database (`RDS-SG`) with an Inbound rule allowing traffic on the appropriate port (eg 3306) from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `RDS-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG` in the inbound rule.

If the Lambda function also needs to connect to the Internet, then there will need to be a NAT Gateway in the public subnet of the VPC.

Comment: Could I not put the lambda function in the same SG as the Aurora instance?

Comment: There is no such concept as "putting resources in the same security group". Rather, resources are _associated_ with a security group. Multiple resources can be associated with the same security group, which means that the rules apply to each of those resources, but they share no special capability from the fact that that have the "same" security group. If two resources associated with the same security group wish to communicate, then the security group will need to explicitly **allow an inbound connection from itself** (by referring to its own ID).

Comment: right. I have in that security group both inbound and outbound connections for that security group listed for itself. I'm not sure why it's timing out.

Comment: You can debug by temporarily opening up the entire security group to verify that it works, then progressively tighten the security. If opening the security group does not fix the problem, then you know it is being caused by something else.

Comment: So I set the security group to allow inbound of 0.0.0.0/0 and it still timed out. This is the security group that the RDS says it is using.

Comment: Great! This means that the problem is not related to security groups! Some things to investigate: Is the Lambda function connecting to  Aurora via a **private** IP address (or is the DNS Name resolving to a private address)? Any non-default NACL settings? Can you connect to Aurora from an EC2 instance in the same VPC? In fact, have you managed to connect to Aurora from _anywhere_?

Comment: John, we have an EB instance that is able to connect as well as myself when I associate my IP with that SG. I’ll have my app spot out the name the uri resolves to. I don’t believe I noticed any weird NACLs but I’ll double check and post back.

Comment: Ok so I see two VPCs in the VPC list. I looked at the NACL for the VPC the RDS resides in (which is also the default VPC) and verified the 3 subnets in question are the ones defined in my serverless.yml. There IS a non-default VPC that exists though. I spit out what the endpoint resolves to and it IS a private 172.32.x.x IP address. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would suggest: Temporarily set security group to allow incoming from `0.0.0.0/0` or the CIDR of the VPC. Launch an Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet of the same VPC. Login and then try to connect to the database using mysql command-line. If that works, then the networking is fine. You can then work on getting the Lambda function to connect.

Comment: I spun up an ec2, associated it with the default vpc, associated it with the lambda sg. At first I wasn’t able to connect. Then I added 0.0.0.0/0 as an outbound rule on the SG. Now it works, both on EC2 and lambda! This makes sense with it having a different sg that it needs to be able to “reach out” to get to the other sg. I then updated 0.0.0.0/0 to the SG of the RDS SG, still good! If I associate both my lambda AND the RDS with the same SG what outbound rules would I need? I’m treating a SG like I would a firewall alias which can bind to one or many addresses.

Comment: I guess the only time I need to do an outbound rule is if it’s going to another resource that isn’t associated with that SG? Or do you need a mapping to itself to access resources within its SG?

Comment: I still recommend the above approach — one SG for the Lambda function (allow all Outbound) and one for RDS (allow 3306 inbound from Lambda SG). It's normally safe to allow all outbound on a security group since you can "trust" your own code. If you do lock it down, make sure it can still send logs to CloudWatch Logs (presumably port 443).

Comment: Yea I’m definitely associating a different Sg for my lambda functions, it was a question for my own edification. If I have a SG “A” and two resources associated with “A” they won’t be able to talk to each other let’s say port 22 unless there is an Innound rule for port 22 (or type SSH) and SG “A” as the source AND and an outbound rule allowing SG A as a destination (or 0.0.0.0/0) with the SSH type (or all) is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The security group is applied independently to each resource.

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much!